# Add a custom domain to a Google Drive website?

Tags: domains

Is possible add a custom domain to a website created with Google Drive?

Comment: yes: http://devtunes.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/how-to-host-website-in-google-drive.html

Comment: That article shows how to set up a frame forwarding for the domain name to the Google Drive website, but it would not be truly hosted at the domain name.

Comment: No you can't as Google wants you to use their domain.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a host name to a Google Drive hosted website in the proper way such that content gets served at that domain name.    You can however set up a domain to redirect there or to [frame forward](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=78) to the Google Drive content.